# Which file contain the recent booted time

Tags: linux

Is there a file that logs when was the computer last booted?
I prefer not to use any shell command for eg., `who -b`.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably `/var/run/utmp` or `/var/run/utmpx`.

I used strace to determine which files were accessed.

```
$ strace who -b  &| grep open
...
access("/var/run/utmpx", F_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/run/utmp", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
...
```

Then you can read that `man 5 utmp` that contains login records.

Moreover from the manual you can get the info that it has BOOT_TIME

```
       The file is a sequence of utmp structures, declared as follows  in  <utmp.h>  (note
       that  this is only one of several definitions around; details depend on the version
       of libc):

           /* Values for ut_type field, below */

           #define EMPTY         0 /* Record does not contain valid info
                                      (formerly known as UT_UNKNOWN on Linux) */
           #define RUN_LVL       1 /* Change in system run-level (see
                                      init(1)) */
           #define BOOT_TIME     2 /* Time of system boot (in ut_tv) */
```

You can read more about it on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp